# Can I pass through the airport security with a de-activated Bazooka?

Tags: air-travel, airport-security, british-airways, firearms

My flight is from Washington, D.C. (IAD) to London Heathrow , with British Airways.

**Important Details**

- The Bazooka will be bought legally from a shop in Maryland
- British Airways' website explains in details [the policy](http://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/baggage-essentials/liquids-and-restrictions) regarding *decommissioned* firearms.
- The Bazooka is de-activated. [UK Violent Crime Reduction Act 2006 Section 38](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2006/38/section/38) states:

> “de-activated firearm” means an imitation firearm that consists in something which was a firearm but has been so rendered incapable of discharging a shot, bullet or other missile as no longer to be a firearm.

- I have no problem in handing the case to the flight crew and getting it back upon arrival but I am not willing to ship it as an extra bag and risk losing it.

Is it possible for the security to stop me from having it on board even that it's allowed on the aircraft?

[image: The real size]

[image: The compact size inside the case]

Comment: Most entertaining question I've seen on this site in a long time. Looking forward to the answers.

Comment: "Is it possible for the security to stop me from having it on board even that it's allowed" - I'm sure that answers will cover this, but security can stop you from boarding/taking objects on board for pretty much any reason they like.

Comment: I'm giving you a +1 just for the bazooka.

Comment: I'd stop you just for the hoodie, let alone the bazooka :)

Comment: Without reading the details, think the answer is; OF COURSE NOOOOO

Comment: -1 I'm sorry but I do not believe your questions are serious. You've recently asked about bringing deactivated bazookas, [bullet-proof vests](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48536/can-i-wear-a-bulletproof-vest-while-traveling-on-british-airways-from-heathrow) and [gold bars](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50882/can-i-fly-with-a-gold-bar) on planes. It seems vanishingly unlikely that any single person would be interested in bringing such items on planes in such rapid succession.

Comment: I don't know about bazookas but this is what happened when someone tried to transport a [medieval-style cannon barrel](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/10/28/tsa-cannon-luggage-maui_n_6064982.html). Is the bazooka a precaution in case the bullet-proof vest isn't enough to protect the solid gold bar?

Comment: In any respect, it is nothing to do with BA. The TSA not allow you airside with weapons, inert or otherwise.

Comment: @Calchas If the OP is a courier, he should know better than to trust professional and legal matters to strangers on the internet. "Oh, I'm sorry your bazooka didn't turn up. People on the internet said it would be OK but the TSA confiscated it," really doesn't cut it as an excuse to a client.

Comment: @DavidRicherby You're quite right of course :)

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22740763#22740763 @DavidRicherby.

Comment: Interesting question I have to say... - Whether it's disabled or not, it's not going to get through an airport

Answer (score 21, accepted):

TSA isn't going to let you anywhere near the gate with that.  They don't care about deactivated.  Looks real/it's real as far as they are concerned.

Since someone complained about a lack of sources:

https://www.tsa.gov/traveler-information/firearms-and-ammunition

Realistic replicas of firearms:  No.

Edit:  They've changed the page.  Now it says:

Replica firearms, including firearm replicas that are toys, may be transported in checked baggage only.

Comment: @Lohoris The point is the question was looking at a non-issue.  It doesn't matter what BA would do as he won't get it there for them to do anything about it.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Look at bullet point #4.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Oops. I missed that.

Comment: Warning. Warning. @LorenPechtel Clearly has *bullet* points... :P

Comment: I think the content of the linked webpage has changed since you last quoted it. If this is the case, care to update the answer?

Comment: @JoErNanO While the exact wording has changed it still says replica firearms are checked only.

Answer (score 40):

[BA's website](http://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/baggage-essentials/liquids-and-restrictions) is crystal clear:

> All firearms (including replica and decommissioned) and ammunition are restricted under UK law and may be carried only with advanced notification and with the appropriate licences and documentation.
>   
> ...
>   Each case containing firearms or ammunition is subject to a £50 charge at check-in each way to cover the cost of our specialist firearms and ammunition handling partner.
>   
> ...
>   All passengers intending to travel with firearms or ammunition must ensure they have the required documentation and licences for them. This includes export/import licences and authorisation from local and national authorities.

And no, you won't be able to carry it in the cabin, it will have to be checked into the hold.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however it looks like the security guys can stop me from getting through even if BA allowed it. I would appreciate more details about that and why I am not allowed to have it as a handbag, the case is not much different than a suitcase

Comment: @User Possibly because you could scare the living c**p out of other passengers and crew if you brandished it.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany if it was even a replica of a gun I would not have bothered asking the question but I can't scare people with a Bazooka! They would beat me to death when I open the case and it's take few minutes to assemble it

Comment: @User: That's why you assemble a Bazooka in the bathroom. Duh.

Comment: @Jonas ok, then what? why would I go out of the bathroom to scare them? surrender or I shoot? you kidding right? replica firearms are banned for a reason but defiantly not a bazooka

Comment: @User: Yeah, you would kick open the bathroom door and scream "Kaboom suckers!" (or something more sensible). On a more serious note, a Bazooka is scary - if people are afraid of a small bullet, they sure are not going to take a portable rocket launcher lightly. Anecdotally, I've seen the face of some idiot officer who stood behind a bazooka when giving the command to fire; since then I know that it's scary on both sides.

Comment: @Jonas I grew up around them (and thats why I am buying one because I want my son to see a real one) and you can easily tell if it's loaded or not

Comment: @User: you and I can. That doesn't mean people who have never held one can, as well.

Comment: Seems to me that a bazooka IS a firearm.

Comment: There was a funny case in 2012 where a passenger in the US tried to bring a petrol-powered **chainsaw** on board as carry-on. They had to chuck away the petrol (because it's explosive) and they **weren't allowed the chainsaw in carry-on** (it's useless as a weapon without fuel, but *it's still a freaking chainsaw*... might be alarming...) but they were allowed to check the chainsaw in to the hold. [Here's the TSA's blog about it](http://blog.tsa.gov/2012/01/tsa-week-in-review-gassed-up-chainsaw.html), other news outlets report that they had to check it in but I can't find a quality link.

Comment: @user568458 If you really have a son and you really want him to see a bazooka, take him to the [Imperial War Museum](http://www.iwm.org.uk/collections/item/object/30035979).

Comment: @user568458 A chainsaw, even one that's not running, can do quite serious damage when swung at someone or something. They don't allow you to take baseball bats into the cabin for the same reason, and larger photography and video tripods.

Answer (score 21):

Ignoring the fact that it's a bazooka, are you sure it isn't too big for cabin baggage anyway ? Even dismantled, it looks quite long.

BA's maximum size for cabin baggage is: 56cm x 45cm x 25cm
(see: http://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/baggage-essentials/hand-baggage-allowances )

Is it less than 56cm long dismantled and boxed up ?

If not, you don't have to worry about security, as BA won't let it on.

Comment: He could buy a seat for it!

Answer (score 7):

In a case of life imitating art (or rather Stack Overflow), unsurprisingly [it would seem](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-49159680) that you cannot take a missile launcher (close-ish to a bazooka) in checked luggage, let alone as hand luggage.

Key quotes from the BBC article in case the link goes stale (cut to leave only parts relevant to this answer):

> US airport security officers have confiscated a missile launcher from
>   a passenger's luggage in Washington.
>
> The Transport Security Administration (TSA) said ...
>   *"Fortunately, the item was not a live device."*
>
> Military weapons are not permitted in checked or carry on bags.

Comment: Just to let you know that man wasn’t me

Comment: Life didn't imitate art, [Stack Overflow has prescience protocols for answering questions before they're asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9135/135695).  (Really, Jon Skeet has them but the rest of us [gain powers by association](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/08/cross-site-account-associations/))

Comment: it wasn't even a missile launcher in this case, but an empty shipping container for munitions to be loaded in a missile launcher on board certain USAF C-130 gunships...